# How can I write generic code that will be inherited?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm trying to write some generic code in a parent class that gets inherited. However, I'm struggling with the type-ing of some of the variables. Take the code below:

```
class A {
    protected:
        std::vector<void*> struct1;
        std::vector<void*> struct2;
        std::vector<void*> struct3;
    public:
    A::~A()
    {
        for(decltype(A::struct1)* i : A::struct1) {
            free(i);
        }
        for(decltype(A::struct2)* i : A::struct2) {
            free(i);
        }
        for(decltype(A::struct3)* i : A::struct3) {
            free(i);
        }
    }
}

class B {
    protected:
        std::vector<b*> struct1;
        std::vector<b*> struct2;
        std::vector<b*> struct3;
}

class C {
    protected:
        std::vector<c*> struct1;
        std::vector<c*> struct2;
        std::vector<c*> struct3;
}
```

(where `b` and `c` are structs).

I'm getting issues with the iterator (`a value of type "void *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "std::vector<void *, std::allocator<void *>> *"`), which makes sense. But class A will never be directly used, only B and C, so A won't run into that issue ever because the structs will have proper types.

Comment: what is this code supposed to do? Why are you using `void*` ? Why pointers in a `vector` ? What is `decltype(A::struct1)*` supposed to do? Why `free` ???

Comment: You probably want to look into templates.

Comment: That's not generic code, that's "throwing entire type system down the drain with 99% chance of UB" code. We may be able to suggest some solution if describe your actual problem instead of your attempted solution, but this one looks unrecoverable.

Comment: There's a lot of code that I didn't include, I just tried to make a minimal, verifiable example. `A` is using `void*` because `b` and `c` are 32-bit/64-bit versions of some data, so `A` doesn't have a way to reference this bc it's bit-agnostic. I'm using `free` because it's a vector of pointers to struct. `decltype(A::struct1)* ` because the code should reference the variable type that it ends up becoming (whether it's `b` or `c`)

Comment: @ChrisMM I looked into template, but I couldn't figure out how to make only the member variables templated, and how to define what type they should use

Comment: As the error says: `decltype(A::struct1)` is `std::vector<void*>`, so `decltype(A::struct1)*` is a pointer to such a vector. Why not just `auto`? In C++ don't use malloc/free, but new/delete

Comment: You can't "override" member variables - you're only hiding the names of the inherited ones.

Comment: " I'm using free because it's a vector of pointers to struct. " really sorry, but that doesnt make sense. In c++ structs are classes and `free` is rarely correct in c++. Next, `decltype(A::struct1)* ` is just a pointer to a `std::vector<void*>` but not something which an element of that vector can be converted to

Comment: this isnt a minimal verifiable example for your question, because it has many errors not related to your question https://godbolt.org/z/dGe27R.  The error you ask for I didnt find

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean that you wanted classes like `B` to inherit from `A` so that the destructor will destroy the contents of the `vector`s?

```
template<typename T>
class A {
protected:
    std::vector<T*> struct1;
    std::vector<T*> struct2;
    std::vector<T*> struct3;
public:
    A::~A() {
        for(auto i : struct1) {
            delete i;
        }
        for(auto i : struct2) {
            delete i;
        }
        for(auto i : struct3) {
            delete i;
        }
    }
}

class B: public A<B> {
}
```

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` would be better, rule of 3/5/0 is broken currently.

Comment: Ok, but one step at a time. There is no feedback from the OP yet.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I want!

Comment: Ok, @Jarod42 Now is the time to update my answer with `std::unique_ptr` vectors!

Comment: using seems even enough. inheritance is unneeded.